# Spring boot project runs in IDE but the jar files doesnot run

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have got a new error but I dont know how this occured.
**Problem:**

I have a spring boot application which runs fine in the IDE. But when I build the project and run the jar file with

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar myapp.jar
```

I faced the issue of **UnsatisfiedDependencyException**

**Error Log**:

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-03 14:43:03 ERROR SpringApplication:771 - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'firstServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'secondService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Bean with name 'userServiceImpl' has been injected into other beans [thirdService] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at com.fusemachines.lms.LmsApplication.main(LmsApplication.java:22) [classes!/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [fuse-ai-2.8.0.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [fuse-ai-2.8.0.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [fuse-ai-2.8.0.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [fuse-ai-2.8.0.jar:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Bean with name 'userServiceImpl' has been injected into other beans [codeHubLinkService] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        ... 27 more
```

I am quiet confused, why it runs in IDE but running the jar gives issue.

I find the similar issue [here](https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot/archives/2017/07/20) And it says: **the order that beans are loaded isn’t deterministic so you may see this in some environments and not in others.** But I could not understand the cause of this issue.

Comment: Have you looked into the suggestion from the error message? "consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example." This may give you more insights. Also, **check which flags your IDE is using** when running from it; do you still get the error if you run the jar with those flags?